# Passing events in child component - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm really weirded out on this error, when I try to pass an onClick handle ever from parent component to the child component, The error persist in the ParentComponent, in the renderHeroesList function. The error in console is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. Here's my code:

```
deleteHeroes(){
        console.log('asd');
    }

    renderHeroesList(){
        if(!this.props.loading){
            return this.props.data.map(function(list) {
                return <HeroesListComponent key={list.id} list={list} onDelete={this.deleteHeroes.bind(this)} />
            });
        }
        else {
            return (
                <tr><td colSpan="5"><Loading /></td></tr>
            )
        }
    }
    render(){
        return(

            <Grid>
                <Row>
                    <Col lg={12}>
                        <Link to={'reactjs/heroes/create'}><Button style={{marginBottom:'20px'}} className="pull-right" bsStyle="primary">Create</Button></Link>
                        <div className="clearfix"></div>
                        <Table striped bordered hover>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Description</th>
                                    <th>Created At</th>
                                    <th>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                    { this.renderHeroesList() }
                            </tbody>
                        </Table>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Grid>
        );
    }
```

Comment: it looks like `this.props.data` isn't ever being defined, Can you show where you get `this.props.data` from

Comment: Actually the this.props.data is working properly if I remove the onDelete props in <HeroesListComponent /> that's why it's really weird that suddenly it displays an error when I add the onDelete props